# parse XML file that contains unicode characters in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse one XML file that contains some unicode characters.I tried to parse the file using NSXMLParser but i am unable to parse XML.Parser stops when it encounters any unicode characters.

Is there any other good solution to parse XML file with unicode letters?

Please suggest.

Comment: you mean didfoundcharacters recognize response in parts...?

Comment: No. I mean my XML contain some italian language characters and i want to parse this XML so i can get all of these characters.

Comment: Is the XML you are trying to parse well-formed? Are the unicode characters properly escaped?

Comment: YES XML is well formed but unicode characters are not properly escaped.

Comment: What does the parser's -parserError method return?

Comment: I have the same unicode parsing issue. XMLParser's parseErrorOccured says Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=9 "(null)" UserInfo={NSXMLParserErrorColumn=21, NSXMLParserErrorLineNumber=1, NSXMLParserErrorMessage=PCDATA invalid Char value 8. I'm trying to find any solution with which the issue would be subsided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried TBXML for iPhone http://www.tbxml.co.uk/